# Shopware 6 Plugin Api get Product data with selected field to reduce response payload

Tags: api, plugins, entity, criteria, shopware6

We created a plugin and now we want to get selected fields only on the response, to minimize the response payload.

We are aware that criteria "includes" will help based on the URL
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria

In the Array of `$criteria` we can see what "includes" is added like filter but does not give the selected fields

Please help what I am doing wrong?

EXample

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
$Criteria = new Criteria();
$Criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $productId));
$Criteria->setIncludes(array('product-alias' => array('name')));
$productRepo = $this->productRepository->search($Criteria, $context);
```

I have tried

```
$Criteria->setIncludes(array('product' => array('name')));
$Criteria->setIncludes(array('name'));
```

Comment: It should work. Includes overwrites the includes. Please provide more contextual code of the problem, where exactly are you calling setIncludes?

Comment: We have created a Plugin to get Parent Child relation in different way. So when perform product search on product ID - we only wanted "name" field in the response no calculatedPRice, no customfield, no other details then "Product name" at that moment.
"includes" looks as the best option. as we are using Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria class it has setIncludes option but still all the product information in the response payload is received (for context using sales channel context)

Answer (score 1):

The `includes` collection is only used when serializing the objects for the response json, as you can find in the [`JsonApiEncoder`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/027efc5bd32b6e91475784e874f6157fc8a76fe5/src/Core/Framework/Api/Serializer/JsonApiEncoder.php#L47). It's not in effect when fetching mapped objects internally, as it could lead to conflicts with only partially mapped objects. You could of course just use the `JsonApiEncoder` internally to encode a collection of entities to receive a response object including a subset of the data.